# How do I select specific lines from a file based on line number?

Tags: python

I have a class which takes in the name of the module to be tested. Then the class scans though a master text file and finds the files that need to be compiled based on the module selected.

This is what I have so far:

```py
class Module():

    def __init__ (self,name):
        self.name = name
        module_start_line = []

        with open('master_module_list.txt', 'r') as master_list:
            for start_no, master_lines in enumerate(master_list):
                if re.search('module ' + self.name, master_lines):
                    module_start_line.append(start_no)
                    print(module_start_line)
```

```
module eeprom_top
../../../project_ip/eeprom_ip/src/eeprom_pkg.vhd
../../../project_ip/eeprom_ip/src/eeprom_top.vhd
module fan_ip
../../../project_ip/fan_ip/src/fan_pkg.vhd
../../../project_ip/fan_ip/src/fan_pkg.vhd
module backplane
../../../project_ip/backplane_ip/src/backplane.vhd
```

So if the user types in "fan_ip" then I want to copy the two lines after `module fan_ip` from the text file.

I am fairly new to python so feel free to correct me on my previous code.
I am using python 3.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `readline` method to read one line at a time, and keep a count of what you've read to determine the line number of each.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more? I think I wold put ```readline``` in a loop and check to see if the line contains the string but I am just stuck on even how to increment until i run into the next "module" keyword.

Comment: About what?  How to use `readline`?  What is preventing you from trying to use it?

Comment: I am trying to use ```while master_list.readline():``` followed by ```if self.name in master_list.readline():```, and the program does not enter the ```if````

Comment: I believe it reads one line from the file and returns a string...which would not work for a while loop because an empty line still returns a new line character.

Comment: And if you call it a second time, what line will it return?

Comment: The next line, that explains why when it was skipping every other line when I try and print the line.

Comment: I figured out how to use ```readline``` and I was able to do what I wanted with it, thank you for the help.